# Spring Security Auto Login not working inside iFrame in IE browser

Tags: java, internet-explorer, iframe, spring-security

My application is using spring security for authentication and authorization purposes. 
To implement a requirement, we needed to do first auto login and then show a particular page to the user.

I made required changes in my source codes and did auto login through spring security api.

As per the client requirement our application needed to be run inside an iframe.
The above implementation is working fine in Chrome and Firefox browser but not in IE.

In IE, it is always showing me the login page(NOTE: Since I am doing auto login, this behavior should not have happened)

If I am directly invoking my application without iframe in IE then it is working fine.

Example:
Say my application URL is http://example.com

If I am running code like  in IE, then login page is getting displayed.

But if I am direcly running (address bar) http://example.com in IE, then the required page is getting displayed with auto login happened.

Can anyone give some idea to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I found the solution after searching a lot in Internet.

Seems like IE is restricting the cookies when the application is running inside iFrame.

The problem lies with a W3C standard called P3P (Platform for Privacy Preferences). Here this will allow Internet Explorer to accept your third-party cookie.

So to solve this problem one need to send the a particular header on the page that allows cookie.

Example:

**response.addHeader("P3P","CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");**